# How are Trustzone Components used in i.MX53?

Tags: arm, trustzone

Can anyone explain how TZ technology is enabled in I.MX53 ? I am totally confused since internet says i.MX53 board has Trustzone enabled but all i can find is an interrupt controller  in it. Where are the rest of the components as given in requirements of ARM trustzone? (TZPC TZMA etc).

Comment: See [Handling ARM trustzones](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12334069/handling-arm-trustzones).  Is there something specific to the iMX53 that you need to know about?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Trustzone is buildin in the system and bootup in TrustZone mode.   How this is possible is because of the HAB mechanism (High Assurance Boot bootchain) - which always boot into the Secure World first.

First this is how the bootup logic is burned into eFUSE:

[image]

Next are the bootup sequence:

[image]

[image]

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4581.pdf

Secure boot itself is configured via CSF:

https://community.nxp.com/thread/428505

For interrupt handling it always pass through the secure world first, before reaching the non-secure world, and for this it is called "Injecting interrupt" into non-secure world.

http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~edson/disciplinas/mc404/2012-2s/anexos/IMX53-tzic.pdf

For more info read these:

http://genode.org/documentation/articles/trustzone

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/IMX53QSBRM.pdf

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/application-note/AN4581.pdf

https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/DWF13_AMF_IND_T0291.pdf