# Handling ARM TrustZones

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, trustzone

ARM has something called TrustZone.
As per ARM documentation , it gives that a process can run in Secure / Non-Secure World.

1. What does the Secure / Non-Secure World means.
   Is it related to Processor executing modes or it is related to setting the permissions of    memory regions or something else.
2. Is there any relationship between the 7 operating modes of ARM and the Secure / Non-Secure         Worlds.
3. How to enable the TrustZone in ARM.
4. From Which version of ARM is this introduced.
5. Is it mandatory to use this TrustZone.
   Does linux kernel uses this TrustZone extension.

Kindly help me in understanding this.

Answer (score 34):

http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/index.html is a pretty good introductory document that gives an overview of something a little bit too complex to be satisfactorily explained by typing into a text box. But I'll try to answer your direct questions below.

1. It refers to an additional privilege option orthogonal to the execution modes. Secure world has the ability to make memory accesses tagged as secure, but can also make non-secure accesses. Normal world can only make non-secure accesses. In addition, certain processor configuration options are only accessible to Secure world. The intent is to isolate secure software in a simple environment where it cannot be (directly) vulnerable to software exploits in the device's main operating system or application software.
2. None, apart from it adding an additional "monitor" mode. This monitor mode is used for the "context switch" between Normal and Secure world.
3. TrustZone isn't enabled, it is implemented (or not).
4. TrustZone was introduced in the Security Extensions to ARM architecture version 6. The first processor supporting it was ARM1176. All Cortex-A processors support it.
5. "No", although since TrustZone-capable processors start executing in Secure state on power-on, if the boot loader does nothing to change the security state, all software will run as Secure (removing any security benefits). No, the TrustZone environment is explicitly intended to run alongside your OS, not to be directly integrated into it. For some platforms, the Linux kernel performs Secure Monitor Calls to request Secure world to change certain system configuration options.

Comment: 1. OMAP 4430 dual core processor runs on Cortex A9 which is ARMv7. And ARMv7 supports TrustZone. Is trustzone features enabled in OMAP4430. How to check if it is enabled or not.

2. What are the kernel level code changes required to support trustzone

Comment: As I said in my response - TrustZone isn't something you "enable", so unless you explain to me in more detail what you want to know I cannot help you. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @unixsmurf <<all software will run as Secure (removing any security benefits). I THINK here you wish to say NON-SECURE. Correct me if I am wrong. else you can edit to reflect NON-SECURE.  THANKS for the detailed answer :)

Comment: @kumar His answer is correct.  The reason is that *secure* is *privileged*, so code unware of *TrustZone* will still run without any modification (Ie, Linux Kernel, VxWorks, etc).  In order to host a *normal world*, you need something in the *secure world* to host it.  So by default things run in the *secure world*; On some devices, the SOC boot code switches to *normal world* automatically, but that boot code must configure the *normal world* to be able to run an OS.

Comment: Thanks @artlessnoise, that is a useful clarification.

Answer (score 20):

To supplement **UnixSmurfs** answer,

> What does the Secure / Non-Secure World means. Is it related to Processor executing modes or it is related to setting the permissions of memory regions or something else.

Mainly it is related to *memory regions*.  All *TrustZone* compatible devices will tag *AXI Bus* access with an **NS** bit.  This bit specifies whether the access is from a *secure* or *normal* world.  In this way, even **DMA** peripherals under the control of the *normal* world can be isolated.

> Is there any relationship between the 7 operating modes of ARM and the Secure / Non-Secure Worlds.

Not really.  However, there is a *between world*, called *Monitor Mode*, and apparently it is the most powerful of the bunch.  *Monitor Mode* is a broker between the *secure* and *normal* worlds.  It can access *normal world* CP15 registers while still having the sytem memory view of the *secure world* (will push the `NS` bit as 0).

> How to enable the TrustZone in ARM.

**Enable** is a bit of an overloaded word. It is built into the CPU as [**unixsmurf**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563188/unixsmurf) points out.  By default *TrustZone* enabled CPUs will boot in the *secure* world.  If you do nothing, you can be oblivious to the fact the CPU is *TrustZone* capable.  Only by setting up a *normal* world and handing control to it, will *TrustZone* be used; possibly this is what you mean by **enable**.

> From Which version of ARM is this introduced.

There are two flavors:

1. *TrustZone* compatible.
2. *TrustZone* enabled.

Section 4.2 of the *TrustZone Security Whitepaper* answer this. The *ARM1176JZ(F)-S*, *Cortex-A8*, *Cortex-A9*, *Cortex-A9-MPCore* and *Cortex-A5* support *TrustZone*.  The  *ARM1156T2(F)-S* and *Cortex-R4* are compatible; they can be a 2<sup>nd</sup> core in the system.  As newer cores are developed, they may be added to the list; this question is a moving target.

> Is it mandatory to use this TrustZone. Does linux kernel uses this TrustZone extension.

It is not *mandatory*.  There are two roles the *Linux* kernel could play; *secure* and *normal* world.  See [svc-handler-to-smc-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052926/svc-handler-to-smc-call) for some information on the use of *TrustZone* with *Linux*.

Some things not answered which **UnixSmurf** alludes to; you must ensure that all of the *BUS masters* and *slaves* are appropriately aware of the **NS** bit.  This information is *outside* of the CPU information and involves *BUS arbitrators*; another topic which is *book-like*.

See: [**PRD29-GENC-009492C**](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/PRD29-GENC-009492C_trustzone_security_whitepaper.pdf)
         [ARM TrustZone as a Virtualization Technique in Embedded Systems](http://os.inf.tu-dresden.de/papers_ps/rtlws2010_armtrustzone.pdf)
          [Trusted computing building blocks with ARM TrustZone](http://cs.ucsb.edu/~sherwood/cs290/papers/trustzone.pdf)
         [ARM Trusted Firmware](https://github.com/ARM-software/arm-trusted-firmware)

Comment: Is there an update for RPI3 on secure booting from SD card?