# Develop programs for Arm trust zone

Tags: security, arm, trustzone

How can I develop applications that use Arm's trust zone? Specifically, I want to develop a program that can save sensitive data in the secure world.

Should this program run in the normal world or the secure world? I know there are trustlets in the secure world, do I need to develop trustlets? Are there SDK or API
that I can use to directly interact with an existing secure world os or do I need to compile and install my own secure os?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013c/index.html

Answer (score 7):

There are two extremes.  These are documented in the [Software overview](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.prd29-genc-009492c/index.html) chapter of **ARMs** *Security Technology: Building a Secure System using TrustZone Technology*.

### APIs

At the one end of the spectrum, there is only a set of **APIs** which can be called from the *normal* world.  This is detailed in the [SMC calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15052926/svc-handler-to-smc-call) for *Linux*.  For instance, if the device contains a *public-private* key, an *API* call could sign data.  The *normal* world would never have access to the *private* key, but anyone can verify that the device is *original* by verifying the signature.  So the *normal* world is free to forward this request over any communications interface.  This maybe part of authenticating a device.

### Co-operative OSs

In this mode, there is a full blown OS in both the *secure* and *normal* world (called *TEE* and *REE* elsewhere).  The OSs must co-operate with interrupts and scheduling.  They may also use **SMC** calls, [lock free](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lock-free) algorithms and *semaphores* along with *shared memory*.

**ARM** recommends using the *FIQ* for the *secure* world and to leave the *IRQ* for the *normal* world.  Specifically, there are settings to stop the *normal* world from masking the *FIQ* ever.  All of these issue rely on the type of *IPC*, *scheduling*, *interrupt response*, etc that the system needs.

The simplest *Secure* scheduler would always pre-empt the *normal* world.  Only the *idle* task would yield the CPU to the *normal* world.  A more flexible solution would have the *schedulers* co-operate so that both worlds can have higher and lower priority tasks.

Comment: The **API** secure world needs a monitor table (MVBAR) with only the SMC slot populated (offset 0x8).  For an OS, you need the FIQ and IRQ slots to handle interrupts.  If both OS's are paging aware, then you need the *instruction fault* and *data fault handlers*.  Main CPU registers must be saved including NEON/VFP, **IF** both worlds use them.

Comment: *If both OS's are paging aware* portion is untrue.  Only external aborts vector through the MVBAR data and page fault addresses.  So the monitor doesn't need to handle page faults even if the OS's use the MMU.  Typically an external abort will trigger due to [*partition checker*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23125982/what-is-partition-checker-in-arm-secure-mode) issues.

Answer (score 1):

The better way is install a REE OS and a TEE OS in one device. When a program wants to do some sensitive things, the device will change to TEE OS, so you can deal with sensitive date securely. When you have done with sensitvie date, device will change to REE OS. 
But implementing two OS switch on a device is a tough work.

Answer (score 1):

Operating Systems such as [MobiCore](http://www.gi-de.com/en/about_g_d/press/press_releases/G&D-announces-MobiCore%C2%AE-integrated-security-platform-to-support-Samsung-GALAXY-S-III-in-Europe-g19904.jsp) already exist and have been deployed on mass market devices such as Samsung Galaxy S3.

MobiCore is an OS that runs **alongside** Android, so trustlets (= MobiCore apps) can communicate with Android apps via a set of system calls to the [MobiCore driver](https://code.google.com/p/tee-mobicore-driver/), which is the part of the Android OS in charge of communicating with the trusted execution enviromnent.

If you are looking to develop trustlets for MobiCore as explained above, you must become a MobiCore developer, which you could theoretically do by signing up as a [developer for MobiCore's Trustonic venture](http://www.trustonic.com/products-services/developer-program).

If you wish to use ARM's TrustZone technology on your own device / dev board with an open-source secure OS, perhaps you can use OpenVirtualization's [SierraTEE](http://openvirtualization.org/), which seems to be compiled for Xilinx Zynq-7000 AP SOC and also compatible with Android as the rich OS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [OPTEE(Open Sourec Portable Trusted Execution environment) OS](https://www.op-tee.org/index.html). If you are looking for trusted execution environment application examples,  which are also know Trusted Applications(TA), then you can check [this optee trusted applications examples repository](https://github.com/linaro-swg/optee_examples) and [this TA using OP-TEE and Comcast Crypto API](https://github.com/jbech-linaro/comcast_cryptoapi_ta_example).

- Optee os provides following APIs for writing Trusted Applications:

  - Secure Storage APIs for secure storage
  - Cryptographic Operations APIs for encryptiion, decryption of secure credentials and data
  - Secure Element API which help in hosting applications or applets on tamper-resistant platform
  - Time APIs
  - Arithmetical APIs 
    For client side or normal world optee provides:
- Tee client side Apis

You can refer [documentation](https://github.com/OP-TEE/optee_os/tree/master/documentation) here.