# ARM-based commodity hardware without TrustZone?

Tags: mobile, embedded, trustzone

Do you know embedded or mobile commodity hardware that integrate ARM-based processors and which does not support ARM's TrustZone? Do I have to assume that any commodity device (e.g. OMAP platform) which integrates a TrustZone-ready processor (Cortex-A9 and higher) automatically supports these seucrity extensions?

The hardware could integrate simple microcontrollers (Cortex-M) or more complex system-on-a-chip hardware (e.g. general purpose OMAP processors).

A few devices for which I am not sure whether they support TrustZone or TI's M-Shield are:  LG Optimus 3D P920, LG Prada, Samsung Galaxy SI / SII, Motorola Droid Bionic, Motorola Atrix 2.

Comment: Especially when you say you can consider simple microcontrollers, the answer is "of course" but uselessly so, since you've not stated any requirement other than that the core be some sort of ARM.  You can get an STM32F3 discovery for about $10 and have at it - or similar things from many other vendors - but who knows if that would meet your *functional* requirement as well as your *negative feature* one.

Comment: What do you mean by *TrustZone*?  See [How to develop for TrustZone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455011/how-to-develop-programs-for-arm-trust-zone) for different models of *TrustZone*.  If you have complete control of the boot, you can disable it and lock it out.  You want to know what device can I buy where I control the boot code.